# What does sendfile_max_chunk being 0 mean in nginx?

Tags: networking, webserver, nginx

Output of `nginx -v`:

> nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

I have this line in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
        sendfile_max_chunk 0;
```

What does this line mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [default value](https://w10schools.com/posts/237723_sendfile_max_chunk) is `sendfile_max_chunk 0;`;

> When set to a non-zero value, limits the amount of data that can be transferred in a single sendfile() call. Without the limit, one fast connection may seize the worker process entirely.

If NGINX is working well, ignore that setting, but if NGINX slows everything *else* down, you can set a limit, e.g., 512k in [this example](https://www.nginx.com/blog/thread-pools-boost-performance-9x/).

If many cases, zero is used to set the *maximum* value of a .config or .ini parameter, *not* minimum. Though it might seem counterintuitive, that convention avoids having to learn what the actual allowed maximum is for each value: the application using the configuration file "knows" that limit.

Comment: The docs now say "Limits the amount of data that can be transferred in a single sendfile() call. Without the limit, one fast connection may seize the worker process entirely." instead of "When set to a non-zero value, limits the amount of data that can be transferred in a single sendfile() call. Without the limit, one fast connection may seize the worker process entirely."